# Firestore: Some values from my flutter app are not uploaded to Firestore database

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

In my flutter app, user is supposed to enter personal data and then it's getting sent over to my Firestore database. The problem is that `apparently` some data is not getting uploaded and `shows null` at the database webPage. It's quite interesting, because `some other data of the same type is getting uploaded despite the problem`.
`No memory leaks` were found by me. It was checked by printing out the values before sending them out to the database.

```
class AdditionalInfo {

  final GeoPoint coordinates;  
  final String addressName;
  final String timeAndDaysBegin;
  final String timeAndDaysEnd;
  final String daysOfTheWeek;

  AdditionalInfo({
    @required this.coordinates,
    @required this.addressName,
    @required this.timeAndDaysBegin,
    @required this.timeAndDaysEnd,
    @required this.daysOfTheWeek,
  });

 Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>
  {
    'coor': coordinates,
    'adrsNm':addressName,
    'tmNdDsBgn' : timeAndDaysBegin,
    'tmNdDsNd': timeAndDaysEnd,
    'dsFThWk':daysOfTheWeek,
  };
}
```

Then I create object that has that `AdditionalInfo` class and upload it to Firestore - it's simple as that, but some data is getting lost.

Comment: Can you show us what you've done?

Comment: I'm sorry, but my code is a mess and you will probably loose the point while trying to understand it. What I'm trying to say is that 90% of data Is being uploaded, and I'm sure that the rest 10% is being uploaded in the same correct way, but for strange reasons it doesn't show up there, so I'm asking more like if anyone has encountered this problem before or if it's impossible and I made mistake somewhere. But thanks @GaboBrandX

Comment: It will be difficult to help you without code. It could be many reasons, the way you are handling futures, or streams, etc.

Comment: @GaboBrandX, you can check a little part of my code here

Comment: @GaboBrandX ahaha, dude sorry, that was because my function was inside of the state class of one of my widgets.

Comment: Haha, no problem. But as you can see, there is no way we could know that whitout seeing your code. Have a nice day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the function being created inside of the state class of my page's parent widget, turns out that it had to be outside